# Why is Python importing an older version of my module when a new version is in the working directory?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a module I have written called plu, which I have previously called in some directory with `import plu`.

However, I have since created a new version of plu in a new directory which is my current working directory (though the old one still exists in its old directory).

For some reason, when I call `import plu` instead of using the version in the current working directory, python is loading the old module.

Why is this and how can I force python to

1. Stop remembering module locations and making them global variables?
2. Load the correct version of the module?

Comment: You can delete the `plu.pyc` inside the `__pycache__` folder in the previous directory.

Comment: Hi, I have done this. By the previous directory you mean the directory that contains the old module, correct? I have deleted the pychache folder here in its entirety but this does not seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Sorry, it does work, I just needed to also restart the kernel. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

[Shadowcoder has provided an answer as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282300/why-is-python-importing-an-older-version-of-my-module-when-a-new-version-is-in-t/69282566#comment122454759_69282300), which is deleting pycache from the previous folder and then restarting the kernel.